# Tool to convert layout dpi's for different screen densities

Tags: android, xml, layout, screen, resolution

Are there any tools out there that can convert my dpi units for a baseline densitity into another?

When I define my layout-files I design for a screen with 320x480 dpi units. But then it doesn't fit right on small and large devices.

But since we know the baseline dpi's of ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi, why isn't there a tool to just take my width/height definitions in the files and scale them to these different densities, given a default baseline. It should then return the missing layout files, where they would scale right on to these other densities.

It seems straight forward and would save developers tons of time, does anyone know of an existing program to do this?

Comment: yes! this'd be very handy indeed. It's a real time-sucker resizing images into four different sizes the whole time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a tool that allows you to scale/adjust your layouts for tablets and small screen devices and made a blog post about it here: http://onemanmobile.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-scale-your-android-layouts-to.html

Basically, defining your layouts in dp units is not enough if you want your app to fit on all devices and tablets, since there's four different "density-buckets". This tool will allow your layouts to be converted into fitting these density buckets.

I hope the blog, tool and answer will help others, I know it felt good to have my app work perfectly on a tablet with the press of a button.

Comment: I can't see what the problem is with Android layouts, they work great. I read your blog, but no idea what problem you're solving. Seems odd to be talking about a layouts issue, but no screenshots to explain.

Comment: Have you tried your app on a tablet device? Like the galaxy tab 10.1? Does the layout scale right? How about on a device like the HTC wildfire or x10 mini? Is anything cut off? I define everything in dp units, but these two problems occur. I could post screenshots (and I will soon), but they will just show what I just said.

Comment: I test on phones and tablets all the time (including the Tab 10.1). I design the screens so they scale and customise the layout to any screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make any sense. what you're asking for is exactly what Android does.

If you put an image into a folder (like xhdpi) it is automatically scaled for all different device densities.

If you create a layout for a particular class of device, then the correct layout is used for the correct device.

I would advise against designing for specific resolutions of screen - there are too many. Group screens into buckets - e.g. "Phones" and "Tablets", or "Small Phones", "Phones", "Large Screen Devices" - specify criteria, and build layouts for each category. It's a fool's game to build layouts for every screen resolution, there are hundreds of Android devices.

Comment: I'm not asking about images, I'm asking about layout files in xml. Since the ratios between small, medium, large and xlarge densities are known, and layout files has to be defined for each density, is there a tool to ease the conversion process? It seems rather time consuming for me to go through all my dip values and re-calcuate them for smaller and larger density screens.

Comment: You do not need to create a layout for every combination, just the ones that matter most to your application. For example adding a dual-pane UI for tablets. No automated tool can do that for you, it needs doing by a human.

Comment: But what if I need a flexible application that just has to have the same placement and proportion of views in all densities? 

It seems wrong to suggest that a tool couldn't do it, I know the width of a large screen is 400dp and a small screen is 320dp. So why can't a tool read through my layout files for a large screen, find the width definitions and recalculate them for other baselines? 

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you're designing an Android app to look exactly the same, pixel-for-pixel, on every device, then you're doing it wrong. There are hundreds of devices, it's impossible. Android layouts are designed to stretch to screen sizes and densities, with UI components positioned relative to each other (see RelativeLayout). Android apps should be designed so the UI can scale/stretch/split to different categories of screen size & density - considering every screen resolution is completely the wrong way to go about it. Read this page http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I'm not trying to make it look the same pixel for pixel, or for each resolution, I'm trying to make it look proportionally the same with different densities! 

My layout is not stretching right from a normal density to a large- or tablet-density, even though I put my xml file in a "layout-normal" folder.

How do I get the values in the xml layout file for a normal density screen to stretch proportionally to a large density screen? This does NOT happen on its own apparently.

Comment: You need to read the docs, and read some Android books. It sounds like you're specifying dimensions using px (pixels) rather than dp (device independent pixels). You should use dp, not px. Hard to be sure though as you're not being clear what the problem is.

Comment: No, I am not using px values, I know that you are supposed to use density independent pixels.

I will try to be as clear as possible: I have specified my layouts in xml files, most of the viewgroups being relative layouts. All size parameters are in dp units. Dp-units are used for padding, margin and size in some cases. I have now put these files in a folder named "layout-large" (although different naming of these folders seems to have no effect). The layout fits perfectly on a Galaxy S2 (large-density screen), but is proportionally wrong on the Galaxy tablet (xlarge density).

Comment: I'd first of all check that the right layout is being used. If it isn't, then no-one can help unless you clarify EXACTLY what the problem is - ideally with screenshots.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt to help me, but no matter how thorough I define my layout units in dp, it still doesn't scale right. Contrary to all documentation, you cannot define a layout-file in dp and have it proportionally the same on a htc wildfire, galaxy s2 and galaxy tab for example. If you made it work, how do you do it?

Comment: "still doesn't scale right" - that's pretty vague. Add some screenshots (scaled down) to your post.

Comment: Hi. I solved the problem and posted an answer, but I havent gotten around to getting all the right screenshots yet. If you have a tablet available you can test it out for yourself. Kind Regards.